# How shall I generate an id for each record in a database table?

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets

I am following https://www.javatpoint.com/crud-in-servlet
to create an CRUD application in servlets and mysql.

Each user inputs his information in a webpage and submit to the web server, which then invokes a servlet `SaveServlet` to save the information as a record in a database table. The  database table however has an additional "id".
`SaveServlet.java` doesn't create an id for each record. So I was wondering how to create an id for each record?

Thanks.

Comment: When you create the database in MySQL you will have a primary key field `id` which will be configured to autoincrement.  You don't insert the id, the database takes care of that for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask a decent question. Questions need to contain things you have tried, as well as questions other than “how do I do this?”, as we are not going to do your homework. Feel free to edit this question in order to make it meet the requirements.

Comment: @dstudeba Thanks. I see. If a different id is created for each record, is it possible to prevent the same person from typing his same information for a second time?

Comment: @Mary Yes, you will need to query the database to check if the user exists already and then put up a warning message if it matches a user.  Obviously a problem if you have two John Thompsons, but you can avoid that my using emails as login names.

Comment: @dstudeba Thanks. Does mysql provide other ways other than autoincrement to create a unique id?

Comment: @Mary Not sure, I have never needed another method

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jpa/hibernate then your entity must be having the @Id annotation on the record id field (you dont need to set it, it will be done automatically based on you Id generation mechanism defined in the entity class and database schema).

if you are using plain jdbc for persisting records then you need to check the database how primary key is defined. for oracle you can your sequence.nextvalue to set the primary key.